# ng-bind-html to prevent executing scripts in content

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, ng-bind-html, ng-bind

The problem I'm facing is I'm getting data from server which has HTML contents

`<p> hello <a class='mention'data-id='1'>Amerr</a></p>`

Since **ng-bind-html** **Santaize** and it will remove all the potential threats and also attributes like **data-id='1'**. Which I need for my directives. So I use

1. **$compile** for my directive to act on the anchor tag .
2. $sce.trustAsHtml to return the comipled code.

so if there is any text like

```
"<p> {{axy}} /p>\n"
```

**`$compile(html_code)($scope)`**

This will execute code and causes angular to execute expression causing problem.
Help me how to solve this problem.

```js
var controller= app.controller('Homecontrol', function($scope) {

  $scope.body = socket.emit('hello');
  $scope.to_trusted = function(html_code) {
    if (/<[a-z][\s\S]*>/i.test(html_code)) {
      var a = $compile(html_code)($scope);
      return $sce.trustAsHtml(a[0].innerHTML);
    } else {
      return html_code;
    }
  }

});

app.directive('mention', function (){
  return {
    restrict: 'AEC',
    transclude: true,
    template: '<a ng-transclude ></a>',
    replace: true,
   }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.22/angular.min.js"></script>
<p ng-bind-html=toTrust(body) ></p>
```

Comment: Do you have any control over data which comes from server?

Comment: I didn't understand. Do you need to compile or only keep data-* attributes?

Comment: I need to compile the text so that Angular directive will act on the string which contains a Link tag . but if the string contains "{{ }}" angular expression . the compile tries to execute this expression .which causes the problen  @MarcusHenrique

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally did by parsing the string by . Jquery.parseHTML and compiled the required DOM with which needs to $compile for directive  to act on it. and replaced by the DOM.